# Dependency Injection in multiple apps

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, console, ioc-container, ninject

I'm having a Web which reference a Data and Entity layer. Now I want to expand my solution with a Console app that will do some stuff related to the Database, and therefore also have reference to both the Data and Entity layer. In my Data and Entity layer I'm using Dependency Injection all over the place, and was thinking whether I need to declare all the bindings for those injections once more (like in my web app) - or I can share them somehow, so that my Web and Console app uses the same bindings?

My first thought was to create a common library with ALL my bindings and then only call those I needed.. but that lead to unessecary references to a shit load of assemblies.

**In short:** How can I declare my dependency injection bindings once and use them both in my Web app and in my Console app?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with 'bindings'? Are you using a particular DI Container?

Comment: @Mark Seemann - By bindings I mean `kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>();` - and yes... I'm using Ninject, however my question is just in general how to declare my bindings once and use them in multiple apps.

Comment: It really depends on the container. Most have some sort of packaging mechanism - they're called Installers for Castle Windsor, Registries for StructureMap, Modules (IIRC) in AutoFac, but I don't know if Ninject has the same concept.

Comment: @Mark Seemann - You can throw the bindings into a `NinjectModule` and call it from your app... but if I put that `NinjectModule` into a Common library, then the library needs to reference all the assemblies where it's injecting from? ex. to do `kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();` it needs to have a reference to the data layer, which would cause unnecessary many references since my console app only needs to be aware of the Data and Entity layer, not the Services layet etc. that my Web app knows off.

Comment: Yes. Now you've more or less already answered your own question. Is it really worth the effort to modularize bindings to address only two apps? A good rule of thumb is that you can copy and paste once, but the third time you'll need to find a way to make the code reusable. You're not there yet, so YAGNI applies.

Comment: @Mark Seemann.. I see that the YAGNI applies in my case... but my real question is whether its "best practice" to make common library when you have multiple apps (more than 2) using the same bindings. The problem with a common library in my eyes is that the library needs to reference all the assemblies where the classes it needs to inject is, and therefore if one of my apps need to use the common library it also needs to be shipped with all the assemblies the common library is referencing?

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that's best practice. Composing the application is the single responsibility of the Composition Root, and that's basically the only the thing the application's entry point should do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your concern is to keep your business logic assemblies free of Ninject modules you can alternatively add them to own assemblies e.g. EntityBindingModule.dll and tell the kernel to load all of them in your bootstrapper:
`kernel.Load("*BindingModule.dll")`

This way it's just a question of deployment which bindings are added.

NOTE: This requires some kind of convention between the assemblies that are loaded by the bootstrapper and the actual name of the assemblies. In the example above it is that these assemblies end with BindingModule.dll.

Answer (score 1):

I think a layout similar to this could work:

```
Console (Just Data)  
|  
|--> Ref: Data  
|--> Ninject: Load DataModule  

Web (Both Data and Entity)  
|  
|--> Ref: Data  
|--> Ref: Entity  
|--> Ninject: Load DataModule, EntityModule (should wire up the bindings)  


Data  
|  
|--> Ref: Common  
|--> Data.cs  
|--> DataModule.cs -> Bind<IData>().To<Data>()  

Entity  
|  
|--> Ref: Common  
|--> Entity.cs  
|--> EntityModule.cs -> Bind<IEntity>().To<Entity>()  

Common  
|  
|--> IData.cs  
|--> IEntity.cs
```

The [Ninject documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) details how you would use a module in code.

Comment: Interesting approach.. What you are doing is to store the needed bindings for a specific Assembly in a Module in the assembly, so thats its available when it's referenced? - But then again... it would tie me to Ninject, and as a rule number one: Your code should never make it impossible to change IOC.

Comment: Yeah, the way I would set it up is to have a module that has bindings for all the 'bindable types' in the assembly. You then just reference the module on application startup and all the bindings are executed.

Comment: @Richard Nienaber - but that would break the principle about never make your code reflect which IOC to use... by doing as your approach shows then I tie myself to Ninject?

Comment: I don't think so. That principle refers to the actual 'business logic' of your application which the IoC definitely shouldn't permeate. If/When you change your IoC container, you will have to update the code that binds those types together. Your code has to reference the IoC container at some point but if you're clever about it, you can limit where it does.

Comment: @Richard Nienaber - By letting each assembly have its own Module, then when I need to change IOC I've to go and change all those Modules to reflect the new IOC?

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't change any business logic.

Comment: @Richard Nienaber - No.. but if I come to the conclusion that I need to change IOC I've to go and change all the Modules to work with the new IOC in every assembly, which leads to recompile which leads to... the list of things that can go wrong and also the amount of time needed is equal to infinity..

Comment: "Your code should never make it impossible to change IOC." Is a very stupid statement. IMO if you're going to make this statement you shouldn't use an IOC container at all and should use poor mans DI. To not leverage the specific characteristics of an IOC container that gives it the awesome functionality of it is stupid. This is why MVC dropped the service locator pattern for you to consider and instead created the ObjectResolver dependency that lets you tie in your IOC container but leaves it to you to register all of your stuff however the IOC container wants and that works best for it.